# "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" hierarchical Cluster Analysis in R

Tags: r, vector, atomic, hierarchical-clustering

i would like to portray the 5 Clusters in a dendrogram wie rect.dendrogram but i get an error:

```r
# 5 Cluster in Dendrogramm 
rect.dendrogram(clust5, k=5, border="red")
# Error: Fehler: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Has someone a solution? Do I have to transform the dataset `clust5`?

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to SO. Could you try to provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/13513328), or at least the result of `dput(head(clust5))`

Comment: Hi, sure! Result: c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 2L, `3` = 3L, `4` = 1L, `5` = 3L, `6` = 1L)

MRE:

# 

dist_Cluster_Daten <- dist(Cluster_Daten_stand, method = "euclidean")
dist_Cluster_Daten

# 

clust1 <- hclust(dist_Cluster_Daten, method = "ward.D2")

#

plot(clust1)

#

clust5 <- cutree(clust1, k=5)

Comment: `clust5` is a vector and not the result of a cluster calculation which should return a list whose elements can be accessed by the `$` operator. Hence the error

Comment: Oh wow thanks! I am pretty new in the r-dimension. where should i put the $ operator?

Comment: perhaps start with the examples of [rect.dendogram](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dendextend/versions/1.15.1/topics/rect.dendrogram)